# Allow overflow scroll on disabled fieldset in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a div that I have set to overflow-y: scroll with a max height. Inside the div is a list of inputs. The div is wrapped inside a fieldset tag that has the `disabled="disabled"` attribute on it. In IE11 only, this is preventing the user from scrolling the div so they can see the other inputs in the list.

Is there any way to make sure IE doesn't disable the scrolling of it (preferably with just CSS)? I have tried adding `pointer-events: auto !important;` to the div in hopes of re-enabling scrolling but that did not work either.

I have an example on a jsfiddle available here that you can open in IE11: https://jsfiddle.net/7dwax3ys/4/show

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.pointers {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<fieldset disabled="disabled">
<legend>disabled</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset disabled="disabled">
<legend>disabled with pointer-events applied to div</legend>
  <div class="pointers">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>enabled</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any direct solution available for IE.

To enable the scrolling in IE. You can try to add **disabled="disabled"** to each input tag and remove it from fieldset tag.

Example:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

div.pointers {
  pointer-events: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>disabled</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>disabled with pointer-events applied to div</legend>
  <div class="pointers">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
    <input type="text" value="test" disabled="disabled">
  </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>enabled</legend>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
    <input type="text" value="test">
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

It can fix this issue for Internet Explorer.

[JSFiddle Example link](https://jsfiddle.net/deepak10/3pkcw90u/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can wrapping the fieldset in an extra div and apply below styles.

```
.wrap{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

This is the [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/munni/05p2Ld7v/27/)

Comment: Thank you but that won't work. For one, that makes the legend on the fieldset scroll as well which is not desired, but also in my app, the scrolling div is just one small part within a much bigger fieldset tag that contains many other fields.